# Why the setInterval in javascript does not work properly

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){

        alert("hi");    
    }, 4000);

    var time = 0;
    var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    setInterval(function(){

        time += 1;

        para[0].innerHTML = time;

    },1);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code, I would like to calculate the amount of time when the alert is displayed, I expect it to be 4000, but it only become 9xx after 4 second. Why would this happen?

Comment: Looks ok to me: http://jsfiddle.net/86eaQ/

Comment: I’m not sure how you could ever get 9xx when you’re adding 1000 each time.

Comment: It appears to work for me. Does this behave as you expect: http://plnkr.co/edit/3fTInWHQATqjVk7X2u7o

Comment: sorry guys I have edited my code, I want it to update per millisecond

Comment: Something else must be wrong elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Your `setInterval` call is missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: yeah, per millisecond is not happening. Use Date objects and calculate difference to the start time, since setInterval has a resolution that is more than 1ms.

Comment: sorry my bad again, I have edited

Comment: Your current code shows `4` after the alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` isn’t very precise. The only guarantee it makes is that the time between calls is greater than or equal to the interval passed. In your case, one of the major issues is that the minimum interval is actually specified to be four milliseconds.

You can get a perfectly accurate measurement using `new Date().getTime()` (or `Date.now()`, given support) – this is in milliseconds, and is generally what you should use when doing anything relating to measuring time (or even most animation, just because it’s simpler).

Comment: Is there any resources or documentation which I can refer to?

Comment: @dramasea: [HTML 5.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-setinterval) – see timer initialization, step 7.

Comment: Also, in some implementations, the interval is in multiples of about 15 ms so you'll never get 100 calls in 100ms, no matter how trivial the code. e.g. a timeout interval of 1ms in IE will only run the function about 65 times each second. Firefox runs it about 150 times.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what I said in the comment, this should work:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("hi");    
}, 4000);

var startTime = new Date();
var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
setInterval(function(){
    var timeElapsed = new Date() - startTime;
    para[0].innerHTML = timeElapsed;
},1);
```

Now even if you don't get in on every millisecond, but, say, every 28ms, your time display stays correct.